# <script> tag makes HTML contents disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is such a wierd problem. I have the following extremly simple HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
    test
    </body>
</html>
```

If I run this page in a web browser, I get nothing at all, just an empty page. If I remove the script reference line entirely, then I get a blank page that displays "test", like it should. This tells me that there is some issue in the jquery.js file, but I have tried 3 different versions of jquery and the one I am using is the latest from the jquery.com website. For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know it will turn out to be simple though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`script` tags cannot be self-closing.  You need the closing `</script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Not including the closing tag means the whole content up to and including `</html>` is treated as the body of the `script` element.  Because the document is then incomplete, your browser closes the `script`, `head` and `html` elements and inserts an empty `body` element.

Comment: Doesn't the XHTML 1.0 specification require all tags to be self closing, or no?

Comment: @icemanind From [this site](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/): "XHTML documents served as text/html are parsed using the same parser that is used for HTML". Unless you are serving your page as `application/xhtml+xml`, your browser will parse it according to HTML rules.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its kinda silly its such a simple thing. This did fix my problem!

Answer (score 2):

you need to close your script tag otherwise it thinks everything after is javascript to be executed...

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

The `<script>` tag is not self-closing, so you'll need a separate `</script>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

See [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing HTML and XHTML.

In HTML, the script tag is not self closing, so you must write `<script src="jquery.js"></script>`.

In XHTML, you must set your XML namespace(`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">`) and send the document with the correct mime type.